# Recreating an Android View in OpenGL

Tags: android, view, opengl-es

Android views are generally quite laggy. I was wondering if it could be possible to like recreate them in OpenGL-ES to use hardware acceleration on it. If it was possible i'd guess it would have been done already. Is it usefull or possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) and draw whatever you like. But I would not recommend recreating an existing view. I don't know which views you mean but on my device they aren't laggy at all...

**Update**: My statement that views are already hardware accelerated was disproved (see comment). So I did research and found [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html) (which underlines the contradiction). So hardware acceleration is available in android 3.0+. Still, I wouldn't recommend to reimplement default widgets. There's still a lot you could do wrong and so impact the performance in a negative way.

Comment: Actually, they aren't HW accelerated. ...Unless you're on 3.0+ and the view has hardware acceleration enabled.

Comment: I thought canvas is delegating it's operations to GL and so to hardware? Am I wrong there?

Comment: Perhaps in some custom-baked implementations of android like TouchWiz, but I'm pretty sure AOSP doesn't have it because of compatibility problems with old hardware (like the G1) I can research it further if anyone's curious.

Comment: I updated my post, found an article which confirms your statement.